# Installing Backbone.localStorage in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to install backbone.LocalStraoge from jeromegn. I've tried searching the registry at the npm website but it doesn't show the backbone localstorage. Can anyone help? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Backbone.localStorage uses the web browser's local storage. Node scripts are executed on the server. I don't see why you could use it in node?